# WiringPi pin numbering for RPi 2B and 3B?

Tags: gpio, pi-2, pi-3, wiringpi

What is the pin numbering for WiringPi on the RPi model 2 B and 3 B? The [pin page on wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/pins/) only gives the numbering for Pis with 26 GPIO pins.

### This is not a duplicate

**because the WiringPi library's pin numbering is different to that of the RPi GPIO pin numbers and the Broadcom CPU pin IO numbers.** The proposed duplicate Q&A's do not give the pin numbers for the WiringPi library; only GPIO and BCM pin numbering

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49958/8697

Comment: You obviously did not look at ALL the answers in the duplicate  (or the detailed link above) - the accepted answer is not necessarily the best (IMHO).

Comment: @Milliways I know this was a while ago, but how can you think that any of those answers address this question? Look at GPIO 18 (WiringPi 1). That match is nowhere on the other question. Not every question is a duplicate, and if you're not sure, don't mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The side where your micro sd card is the upper side, the first number is your gpio pin number from the RPi itself (in ascending order) then there is the Broadcom number, and between the parenthesis as you can see are the matching Wiring Pi numbers.

First the left row from up to down:

```
1 3v3 Power
3 BCM 2 (WiringPi 8)
5 BCM 3 (WiringPi 9)
7 BCM 4 (WiringPi 7)
9 Ground
11 BCM 17 (WiringPi 0)
13 BCM 27 (WiringPi 2)
15 BCM 22 (WiringPi 3)
17 3v3 Power
19 BCM 10 (WiringPi 12)
21 BCM 9 (WiringPi 13)
23 BCM 11 (WiringPi 14)
25 Ground
27 BCM 0 (ID_SD)
29 BCM 5 (WiringPi 21)
31 BCM 6 (WiringPi 22)
33 BCM 13 (WiringPi 23)
35 BCM 19 (WiringPi 24)
37 BCM 26 (WiringPi 25)
39 Ground
```

And the right row from up to down:

```
2 5v Power
4 5v Power
6 Ground
8 BCM 14 (WiringPi 15)
10 BCM 15 (WiringPi 16)
12 BCM 18 (WiringPi 1)
14 Ground
16 BCM 23 (WiringPi 4)
18 BCM 24 (WiringPi 5)
20 Ground
22 BCM 25 (WiringPi 6)
24 BCM 8 (WiringPi 10)
26 BCM 7 (WiringPi 11)
28 BCM 1 (ID_SC)
30 Ground
32 BCM 12 (WiringPi 26)
34 Ground
36 BCM 16 (WiringPi 27)
38 BCM 20 (WiringPi 28)
40 BCM 21 (WiringPi 29)
```

Source: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/wiringpi_gpio_pinout

Comment: It would be nice if these were marked on the Pi itself.  What is the best way of locating them - by counting all the tiny pins by hand?

Comment: Well, there are some reference cards for sale that you can use to lay over the pins before you connect the wires, for example [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2263)

Comment: Thanks!  Does that replace the need for a RPi GPIO Breakout Expansion?